# Functions interval question

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the interval of a function.

The following function

$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{-4x}{(x^2-1)^2}$$

I know that the point -1 and 1 in the number line would be gaps in the number but would this because of domain restriction in the original function?

Because I also know that if I the derivative has point that DNE then they can be included in the number line to determine whether the function increase or decrease.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Well I am wondering that if a function for example $f(x)=(x+2)^{(5/3)}$ derivative $(10/9)(x+2)^{(-1/3)}$ can have in the derivative a critical point -2 which DNE in the derivative but it does exist in the original domian

Comment: but I mean it is in the domain but not in the domain of the derivative when trying to find critical points so therefore it could be part of the number line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Following up on the discussion in the comments, it was clarified that the OP is having trouble understanding why the domain of the derivative of a function might not be the same as the domain of the initial function.*

**Answer:** Read [this](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivada#Derivada_de_una_funci.C3.B3n) definition of derivative of a function. As you can see, given a function $f$ with domain $D$, the derivative of $f$ at a point $a\in D$, which is denoted by $f'(a)$ is defined by:

$$f'(a):=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)$$

**if** the limit **exists** and is **finite**, otherwise $f'$ is not defined.

Since $a\in D$, then the domain of $f'$ will be a subset of $D$, but it can happen that the domain of $f'$ isn't $D$. For that to happen it suffices that the limit in the definition of $f'$ doesn't exist or isn't finite.

Here's an example: let $g(x)=\sqrt x$, for all $x\in \Bbb R_0^+$.

Let's try to find $g'$. Let $a\in \Bbb R_0^+$.

$$\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\sqrt x -\sqrt a}{x-a}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\sqrt x -\sqrt a}{(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)(\sqrt x + \sqrt a)}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}\right)$$

If $a\neq 0$, then you get $\displaystyle g'(a)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt a}$, as expected.

But if $a=0$, then the limit won't be finite, therefore $0$ is not in the domain of $g'$. It should be noted that the limit for $a=0$ is only taken for $x$ *to the right* of $0$.

Comment: yes your response makes sense thanks very much.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not defined (not in the domain of) at $x = 1, x=-1$

You must check the limit of the derivative as $x \to -1$ and $x \to 1$ approached from each direction, to understand or determine whether an asymptote, cusp, or vertical tangent e.g. exists there. For example, see the graph of your function is shown below:

By testing the *limit of the **derivative*** as $x \to -1^+, x \to -1^-, x\to 1^-, x\to 1^+$, you will see the $f'(x) \to -\infty, f'(x) \to +\infty, f'(x) \to -\infty, f'(x)\to +\infty,$ respectively. So it turns out that we have two vertical asymptotes, one at $x = 1$, and the other at $x = -1$.

Hence, the neither the derivative nor the function is defined at $x = -1, x = 1$. The only critical point of the function is the local maximum at $(0, 0)$.

[image]

Comment: Fernando, does this help to answer your question?

Comment: Indeed it does.... thanks