# Concave up down question

Tags: calculus

I have quick question regarding concave up and downn.

in the function $f(x)=x\sqrt{4-x}$

the critical point is $\frac{8}{3}$ as it is the local maximum.

taking the second derivative I got $x=\frac{16}{3}$ as the critical point but this is not allowed by the domain so how can I know if I am function concaves up and down assuming I do not havee a graphing calculator.

for my second derivative I got

$f''(x)=6\sqrt{4-x}+\frac{8-3x}{\sqrt{4-x}}/((4(4-x))$

Comment: What did you get as the first and second derivatives? Add it to the question, please. You made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Fernando is a great asker. Why is he only getting my upvote for a clearly posed question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation looks as if it was done correctly.  I get $f''(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot \dfrac{16-3x}{(4-x)^{3/2}}$ for the second derivative.

The function is defined for $x\le 4$, and its derivatives for $x\lt 4$. When you calculated $f''(x)$, the numerator vanished at $\frac{16}{3}$ only. The second derivative is not defined there, so the second derivative does not change sign over the interval of definition. There is hence no change in concavity.

So to decide on concavity, you can just evaluate the second derivative anywhere in the interior of our interval of definition. The result is negative, so the curve is concave down everywhere.

Comment: How can the calculation be fine if he gets a zero of $f''$ not in the domain of $f$?

Comment: Well, it isn't a zero of $f''$. The OP found out where the "top" is $0$. It so happens that the bottom, which is $4(4-x)^3/2$, is not defined there.

Comment: so say I plug in x=3 my in the second derivative my result would be a negative so that graph concaves down?

Comment: The numerator is $0$ nowhere in the second derivative.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Exactly

Comment: @Fernando Recall my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/340107/55235) to your question. The domain of $f''$ must be a subset of $f$. If the expression for $f''$ happens to be defined somewhere where $f$ isn't, it doesn't mean the actual second derivative $f''$ is defined there, it just means that the expression which defines $f''$ can be defined there, but not $f''$ itself. So if you get that $f''$ "has a zero" outside of its domain, then it's not a zero at all!

Answer (score 1):

> taking the second derivative I got $x=\frac{16}{3}$ as the critical point

I assume that you mean that you set $f''(x)=0$ and found a solution of $x=\frac{16}{3}$. This is *not* a critical point. Rather it is an *inflection point*. In other words, this is where the function changes from concave up to concave down (or vice versa). However, since this value of `x` is not in the domain of `f`, **there is no inflection point.**

On the other hand, you can evaluate $f(\frac{8}{3})$. This gives the concavity at the local extremum. This will tell you whether the graph is concave up or concave down and thus whether this is a local minimum or a local maximum.

Comment: sorry I meant inflection point.